# Rotating point symbol to underlying line for QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, line, rotate

The expression below worked perfectly under QGIS 2.18. One simply entered it as an expression for the valve symbol and all valves rotated based on the underlying pipe feature. However it no longer works on QGIS 3.2 due to changes in the `qgsGeometry` functions.

How do I do this in QGIS 3?

```
degrees(
    azimuth(
        start_point(
            geom_from_wkt(geomnearest('WaterPipes02_Vermont', '$geometry'))
            ),
        end_point(
            geom_from_wkt(geomnearest('WaterPipes02_Vermont', '$geometry'))
            )
        )
    )+90
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not look right, and it might be a bug.

Just a work-around, but you could create an intermediate field to store the unique id field of the nearest water-pipe (or line layer).

(1) Open the attribute table of your valve layer (or point layer) and create a tentative field `pipe_id` by an expression below:

```
geomnearest( 'WaterPipes02_Vermont', 'id')
```

[image] `pipe_id` is the `id` of closest pipe in 'WaterPipes02_Vermont'

(2) Go to the layer property - symbology and set `rotation` property by:

```
degrees(
 azimuth(
  start_point(geometry(get_feature('WaterPipes02_Vermont', 'id', "pipe_id"))), 
  end_point(geometry(get_feature('WaterPipes02_Vermont', 'id', "pipe_id")))
 )
)+90
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kazuhito for your quick response. However I seem to be mis-interpreting the first step of your procedure. Should one not be using pipe-id in the geomnearest function as opposed to id? (Essentially we are trying to get the pipe-id values into the new pipe-id field in the valve table)

Comment: @NeilF Yes, you have a `pipe-id` field in the pipe layer, right? Then the second argument in the `geomnearest()` should be `pipe-id`, not `id`.

Comment: Thank you @Kazihuto for your confirmation. I am however still finding difficulty in getting Part 2 to work ie getting the symbol to rotate according to the geometry of the pipe. Can't figure why its not working because it obviously works as per your test/arrow diagram. Must be something silly on my side - will persevere.

Comment: Ack, sorry @NeilF `get_feature()` also has to reflect the name (i.e. `pipe-id`) so it should be `get_feature( 'WaterPipes02_Vermont', 'pipe-id', "pipe_id")`.

Comment: it works perfectly now!! Thank you for your great feedback.

Comment: @NeilF - Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for the prompt re the tick, this is my first time using Stack Exchange. Still need to learn the various tricks, tips and etiquette - I'll get there eventually