# Rotating point symbol to underlying line between two vertices (QGIS 3)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

[Rotating point symbol to underlying line for QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289549) works perfectly when the symbol is between the start and the end point of a line.

Is there a (similar) way to rotate symbols e.g. 90° to a segment of a line between two vertices?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear: what is the difference between the first case (symbol is between the start and the end point of a line) and the second one (between two vertices)? I don't understand what you want to do: can you add a screenshot and additionalinformation?

Comment: Do you want a label at every segment, or a particular segment of your choosing?